# Проблема при установке зависимости в Maven проект

Tags: java, maven, зависимости

Ошибка при установке зависимости `dependency`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
    <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никак не могу найти решения для этой проблемы.

Что это за ошибка? Из-за чего это произошло? И как можно решить? Буду благодарным за ответ :)

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Все `dependency` должны быть в `dependencies`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Любой запрос типа [Пример pom.xml файла зависимости](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80+pom.xml+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) вернёт ссылки, которые покажут, как именно должен выглядеть список зависимостей в файле `pom.xml`.

Например, ссылка на [java-online.ru: **Maven зависимости, dependency**](https://java-online.ru/maven-dependency.xhtml) содержит следующую "секретную" информацию:

> Объявление зависимостей заключено в секции `<dependencies>...</dependencies>`. Количество зависимостей не ограничено. В следующем примере представлено объявление зависимости библиотеки JSON, в которой используется классификатор *classifier* (в противном случае библиотека не будет найдена в центральном репозитории) :
>
> ```xml
> <dependencies>
>    <dependency>
>        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
>        <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
>        <version>2.4</version>
>        <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
>    </dependency>
> <dependencies>
> ```

Аналогичные примеры можно найти и в англоязычной [документации к Maven](https://maven.apache.org):

- [POM Reference :: Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#dependencies)
- [Maven :: Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism :: Dependency Management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-management)

> The cornerstone of the POM is its dependency list. Most projects depend on others to build and run correctly....
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно, остальные списки в `pom.xml` типа `repositories`, `pluginRepositories`, `resources`, `profiles`, `plugins` и т.д. также имеют аналогичную структуру: объявление списка во множественном  числе, внутри списка каждый элемент находится внутри соответствующего XML-элемента в единственном числе:

```xml
<listElements>
    <listElement>...</listElement>
...
    <listElement>...</listElement>
</listElements>
```